# Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' ERROR when trying to multiply a float number with len(list)

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to take a random sample from a list given `SPLIT_SIZE = 0.9`, but I'm having the following error:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'.
```

This is the line of code that is giving the error:

```py
list = os.listdir(SOURCE)
training_set = random.sample(list, float(SPLIT_SIZE)*int(len(list)))
```

where `SOURCE` is a directory containing images.

Comment: The purpose of `random.sample()` is to pick N different items from a sequence.  N must be an integer; it makes no sense to pick half of an item. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Also `int(len(list))` is redundant, `len` always returns an int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of `random.sample` have to be integer type.